# UseSubmitBehavior="false" and binding OnClientClick?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:Button ID="RecoverButton" runat="server" Text="Recover"
    OnClick="RecoverButton_OnClick" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

I kind of figured out `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` overwrites the `OnClientClick` function I was providing.

I went with this then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id$=RecoverButton]").live("click", RecoverButton_OnClick);
});

function RecoverButton_OnClick(s, e) {
    var input = $("[id$=MasterUsername]").val();
    var valid = $dn.s.MailValidation(input);

    if (!valid) {
        // prevent postback here
    }
}
```

But I don't know how I can prevent the postback event from firing up.
I tried doing something like `e.preventDefault()` but it didn't work, ideas?

**Update** thing is both the `__doPostback` and `jQuery`'s click handler seem to fire up at the same time (or maybe ASP.NET's fires first), but I placed an alert on my RecoverButton function and firebug already shows the postback happening while the alert is there, blocking execution.

Comment: @Aristos you are right though, but that didn't answer this particular problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id='<%= RecoverButton.ClientID %>']").live("click", RecoverButton_OnClick);
}
    function RecoverButton_OnClick(event) {
        var input = $("[id$=MasterUsername]").val();
        var valid = $dn.s.MailValidation(input);
        if (!valid) {
            return false; //This cancels the submit event
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: I know this is old, but `.live` is deprecated. Use `.on` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've met the same problem. 
I solved the issue using the following dirty code:

```
  if (!valid) {

     //throw a exception to prevent _doPostBack method running.
     var e = new Error(); 
     throw e;
  }
```

Comment: When validating a form with jquery, and also disabling the button  just before the postback, this is the only thing that worked for me. Using UseSubmitBehavior=false, the function "preventDefault()" does not work.